# Access kerberized ressources from cron job using a keytab

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 which is joined to an Active Directory 2016 by sssd. I have access to several network ressources through kerberos: file shares, oracle and postgres databases. All is good. But I also want to be able access these ressources from a cron job.

I hope to be able to do that with a keytab and k5start. But I cannot get the keytab to work.

I detect the relevant kvno using

```
kinit -c filex
kvno -c filex  krbtgt/XXX.LOCAL@XXX.LOCAL
```

It is 3. Then I create my keytab using ktutil (addent prompts for my password).

```
ktutil
addent -password -p yyy@XXX.LOCAL -k 3 -e aes256-cts
wkt ./yyy.keytab
quit
```

Testing the keytab with

```
kinit -c filex -k -t keytab yyy@XXX.LOCAL
```

results in

```
kinit: Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials
```

Google tells me this means the password is incorrect, but it is not.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: It's not enough to detect just the kvno – for AES you also have to detect the key salt, which is usually _but not always_ the account@REALM, e.g. if the account is renamed, its keys remain unchanged meaning the keysalt is still based on the _old_ name. Make sure to use the `-f` option to addent so that it always derives the key correctly.

Comment: @user1686, Thank you for this. I am not sure I quite follow you. Does addent have a -f option? Could you elaborate, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my own question is that you have to be very careful with case when specifying username (principalname). The case of the username *must* match the case of the sAMAccountName in Active Directory. In my example, I specified yyy@XXX.LOCAL, when in fact it should have been YYY@XXX.LOCAL. Both when creating the keytab and when using it.